# How do I edit a URL so that it forces you to a particular spot on the page it opens?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, html, url

When I post a link, I want to make sure the page opens at a particular place on the page by editing the URL.  Is there a simple way to do that?

I must say  I figured this was a simple enough question that a few minutes of googling should be enough to solve, but this has proven to not be the case.  I'm hoping you all can help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally it's pretty easy, you would append a hash (`#`) and the id of an element (generally in the HTML you would see `<div id="something">` and you would use `#something`.

As an [example on this page](https://superuser.com/questions/627193/how-do-i-edit-a-url-so-that-it-forces-you-to-a-particular-spot-on-the-page-it-op#answers):

```
https://superuser.com/questions/627193/how-do-i-edit-a-url-so-that-it-forces-you-to-a-particular-spot-on-the-page-it-op#answers
```

I had to right click and inspect the element to see the `id`, it helps to have the developer tools/firebug/etc installed and activated (on Firefox/Chrome).

On Safari, you'd need to turn on the dev console I believe.

On Internet Explorer, you probably have to manually search - but someone else may have a suggestion there.

Comment: I've been using the web since there was a web, and I did not know this. I knew about anchors, but not the div id trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If it concerns a page you wrote, (or if they are already present) you can use [HTML anchors](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3).

Otherwise, it's not possible to give a location in a webpage in the URL.

Comment: not true - see nerdwaller's answer...

Comment: @MattDMo This debate has already occurred (even if the comments were deleted), and we are both telling the same thing : the only way to achieve what the asker wants are HTML anchors. And if there are no anchors already on the page, you can't create such link.

Comment: You're right, I should have read through your link more carefully. I can't undo my vote (time limit), but if you make a minor edit to your post I will gladly change it. My bad...